# SQL Logical error

Tags: sql

I thought it's simple but yet it's giving me unwanted result (logical error).
I am querying employee records each with its related loan records (one-to-many relationship).

My problem is that when an employee has i.e 2  loans than the returned rows multiply 2 & when he has 3 loan the result will be 3 rows instant of its exact number of loans.

My SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee, loan 
WHERE employee.staffid = loan.staffid
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: share sample data with expected result and what you getting.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee.* FROM employee, loans WHERE employee.staffid = loans.staffid
```